# Запретить пустой ввод, и разрешить только цифры

Tags: javascript

1) у меня есть javascript

2)мне нужно ограничить его только на ввод цифр.

3)мне нужно запретить пустое подтверждение.

```js
function checkAge(age) { 
  if (age > 18) { 
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return confirm('Родители разрешили?'); 
  } 
} 
var age = prompt('Ваш возраст?'); 
if (checkAge(age)) {
  window.location="2"; alert( 'Доступ разрешен' ); 
} else {
  window.location="3"; alert( 'В доступе отказано');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = prompt("введите строку");
var re = /^[0-9]+$/g

if (re.test(str))
 alert("верно");
else
 alert("не верно");
```

Comment: `+` вместо `*` избавит от проверки строки на пустоту

Comment: @Grundy , не знал, пасибо.